# Amazon S3 + CloudFront + Redirection rules don't work

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

my instance in amazon S3 works perfectly with its redirection rules to folders and files that don't exist on the bucket (their path converts to #arguments):

this

mediocafe.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/redirect/thispath/hopeitworks

redirects me to the correct web

but if i try to access via my cloud front, it gives me a Key not found message.

what should I configure to allow cloud front access S3 files that don't exist and that trigger redirection rules?

Answer (score 2):

Redirect works, the problem was that i was redirecting 403 errors, not 404

Comment: If your bucket is set up to allow "Everyone" the "List" privilege, then the redirect rules need to be against 404 instead of 403... but if "Everyone" has the "List" privilege, that also allows everyone(!?) to list all the files in your bucket(!?)... so perhaps the better option is to tighten up the bucket permissions and go back to 403 on the rules.

Comment: Thanks Michael, very useful comment, perfecting what already works is what makes te difference

Comment: You have stated my philosophy quite elegantly.